# Use MFMessageComposeViewController in iOS7, can not send iMessage/SMS some time

Tags: ios, ios7, message

this is my code :

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
[controller setValue:[[[MyNavigationBar alloc]init] autorelease] forKeyPath:@"navigationBar"];

if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
{    
    controller.body = bodyOfMessage;
    controller.recipients = recipients;
    controller.messageComposeDelegate = self.orderBaseController;
    [self.orderBaseController presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

screen image:
[image: screen image]

problems:

1. someTimes, it can not send message out;(in the app, pressed send button,and the ComposeViewController has dismissed,but the message didn't appear in the system Message List)
2. SomeTimes, it will appear a blank cell in the System Message List,like the image show.(It's all blank, has no message bubbles)；

it works fine in normal iOS device, only have troubles with iPhone4s with iOS7 (maybe iPhone4,too). two guys who use my app founds these problem.

It seems like system bugs,What should I do with it ?

Comment: Post the bug to Apple perhaps? It does sound like an Apple issue instead of an issue with your app...

Comment: Same problem here. Did you ever manage to resolve this?